# InvalidCastException-failed to convert parameter value from a sqlparameter to a string

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am new to application block.

I am trying to insert data in database. Following is the code snap.

```
 private int Id;
    private string Title;
    private string Description;
    private DateTime Start;
    private DateTime End;
    private int User_id;


    public int id
    {
        get
        {
            return Id;
        }
        set
        {
            Id = value;
        }
    }
    public string title
    {
        get
        {
            return Title;
        }
        set
        {
            Title = value;
        }
    }
    public string description
    {
        get
        {
            return Description;
        }
        set
        {
            Description = value;
        }
    }
    public DateTime start
    {
        get
        {
            return Start;
        }
        set
        {
            Start = value;
        }
    }
    public DateTime end
    {
        get
        {
            return End;
        }
        set
        {
            End = value;
        }
    }
    public int user_id
    {
        get
        {
            return User_id;
        }
        set
        {
            User_id = value;
        }
    }
```

### DAC :

```
  public static int addEvent(CalendarEvent cevent)
    {
        try
        {


            SqlParameter[] sqlParam = new SqlParameter[5];
            sqlParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@title", cevent.title);
            sqlParam[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            sqlParam[1] = new SqlParameter("@description", cevent.description);
            sqlParam[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            sqlParam[2] = new SqlParameter("@event_start", Convert.ToString(cevent.start));
            sqlParam[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            sqlParam[3] = new SqlParameter("@event_end", Convert.ToString(cevent.end));
            sqlParam[3].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            sqlParam[4] = new SqlParameter("@user_id", cevent.user_id);
            sqlParam[4].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            return Convert.ToInt32(SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(connectionString, "SaveData", sqlParam));
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
```

SQLHelper Class:

```
 public static object ExecuteScalar(SqlConnection connection, CommandType commandType, string commandText, params SqlParameter[] commandParameters)
        {
            //create a command and prepare it for execution
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            PrepareCommand(cmd, connection, (SqlTransaction)null, commandType, commandText, commandParameters);

            //execute the command & return the results
            object retval = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            // detach the SqlParameters from the command object, so they can be used again.
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            return retval;

        }
```

I am getting error  in object `retval = cmd.ExecuteScalar()`  **Failed to convert parameter value from a SqlParameter to a string**.I  am unable to understand what is the problem.

Comment: i don't know correctly

Answer (score 1):

Your function signature for `SQLHelper.ExecuteScalar` method is

```
ExecuteScalar(SqlConnection, CommandType, string, params SqlParameter[])
```

And you are using

```
SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(connectionString, "SaveData", sqlParam)
```

You have to pass `CommandType`, You are not passing [CommandType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your function call

Use

```
SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(connectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "SaveData", sqlParam)
```

Pass [CommandType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as per your requirement

Additionally I think you need to pass `SqlConnection`, So use

```
SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(new SqlConnection(connectionString), CommandType.StoredProcedure, "SaveData", sqlParam)
```